# Using CloudFormation to launch an AWS autoscaling group with attached EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ebs

I am trying to launch an autoscaling group with a single m3.medium instance and attached EBS using CloudFormation (CFN). I have succeeded in doing everything but the EBS part. I've tried adding the following block to my CFN template (as a property of the [AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration block](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html)):

```
"BlockDeviceMappings": [
  {
    "DeviceName": "/dev/sdf",
    "Ebs": { "VolumeSize": 100, "VolumeType": "gp2" }
  }
]
```

Without this the launch succeeds. When I include it, aws hangs while trying to create the autoscaling group. There are no error messages to help debug this issue. I've tried creating an EBS through aws console and attaching to the launched m3 instance manually, and this works, but I need to do it through CFN to conform to our automated deployment pipeline.

Are there other resources I need to create in the CFN template to make this work?

Comment: To answer the direct question, you only need this embedded property on the launch config, and no other resources. It might just be syntax (see my ans) or limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

After speaking with AWS support, I resolved this issue. It turns out that AWS makes a distinction between an instance-store-backed and ebs-backed ami. You can only add the BlockDeviceMappings property when using an ebs-backed ami, and I was using the other kind. Luckily, there is a way to convert instance-store-backed to ebs-backed, using this procedure:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html#Using_ConvertingS3toEBS

Answer (score 0):

If that's a verbatim block, then you add quotes to volume size (doc is very misleading, as all data types are strings). Here's one that's worked fine for me, and I see no differences:

```
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": {
                        "Ref": "SecondaryDevice"
                    },
                    "Ebs": {
                        "VolumeType": "gp2",
                        "VolumeSize": "10"
                    }
                }
            ]
```

In general, if you need to troubleshoot ASGs, add SNS notifs for launch failures to the auto scaling group (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/ASGettingNotifications.html). You may find that you're on your last hundred gigs of EBS limit (not likely) or that your AMI doesn't like the device type or label you're trying to use (somewhat more likely).

Comment: Thanks. I tried both 100 and "100" but neither one works. Also, I know I'm not running out of EBS space because I can create a new EBS and attach it to my instance through aws console. How would SNS notifications help here? The stack launch isn't actually failing, it just hangs for an indeterminate amount of time. Last tim I tried this I let it go for over 30 minutes.

Comment: Gotcha. Do you need more detail around enabling SNS on the autoscaling group? If the group resource itself finishes creating, then you can use that to get a good error message (i.e. you'll get an email in response to a failed launch with something like "unsupported configuration", which I'm assuming is the underlying cause).

Comment: If you've got a link I can take a look at, that would be useful.